# Proper way to test dynamic class methods in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

My code uses metaprogramming and has dynamic methods. I'm trying to figure out the best way to test them in RSpec3. Below is an example to be tested:

```
module Placements
  class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    class << self
      Placements::Status.unscoped.pluck(:system_name).each do |system_name|
        define_method system_name do
          unscope(where: :archived).find_by_system_name(system_name)
        end
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

With an instance of `Placements::Status` like

```
Placements::Status.create(system_name: "visible")
```

I expect `Placements::Status.visible` method to be present. Since the dynamic method relies on the data in the database, I'm trying to figure out the best way to catch it with RSpec

To create a record and then load a model file again, I use a `before` hook in my test suite:

```
before(:each) do
  create(:visible)
  load 'app/models/placements/status.rb'
end
```

It works, and I can call `Placements::Status.visible`, but it doesn't look very elegant (using factory). Is there a better/proper way to reload a class to look at the records created in the database? Any other before hooks or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Going full on archeologist here...

Interesting use case. The way I might tackle something like this would be to move the setup code into a method that can be called from the test, rather than relying on it being called when the file is loaded. You could then execute the method when the file loads for production usage, but you could run the method in your tests directly for test usage. It might look like this:

```rb
module Placements
  class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    class << self
      configure_data_driven_methods

      def configure_data_driven_methods
        Placements::Status.unscoped.pluck(:system_name).each do |system_name|
          define_method system_name do
            unscope(where: :archived).find_by_system_name(system_name)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Then, the tests could look like this:

```rb
RSpec.describe Placements::Status do
  it "has a visible method" do
    # arrange (setup the test)
    create(:visible)

    # act (do the thing)
    described_class.configure_data_driven_methods

    # assert (that the thing happened)
    expect(described_class.visible).not_to raise(NoMethodError)
  end
end
```

Another alternative is to go the route of `method_missing` where you don't actually create the methods at startup, rather you query the database when a missing method gets called to see if it should be there. This has the disadvantage of being slower to respond when the method is called. But, it has the advantage that methods can be added to the running application without a restart. And, testing this approach would be a simple matter of testing the `method_missing` method.

**EDIT**

After thinking about this a bit more, I think I'd use `respond_to?` like this:

```rb
RSpec.describe Placements::Status do
  it "has a visible method" do
    # arrange (setup the test)
    create(:visible)

    # act (do the thing)
    described_class.configure_data_driven_methods

    # assert (that the thing happened)
    expect(described_class.respond_to?(:visible)).to be true
  end
end
```